# Fibonacci calculator in C, compiled to mips, causes infinite loop

Tags: mips, fibonacci

I am trying to translate my fibonacci c code to MIPS assembly code, however, when I run the MIPS code to my MIPS simulator it doesn't seem to end.

C Code:

```c
int fibo(int n)
{
    if(n<2) return 1;
    else f(n-1)+f(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    fibo(5);
}
```

Assembly Code:

```
main: addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, 0($sp)

addi $a0, $zero, 5
jal fibo; 

lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4

fibo: addi $sp, $sp, -12
sw $s0, 0($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)
sw $ra, 8($sp)

slti $t0, $a0, 2
beq $t0, $zero, ELSE

addi $v0, $zero, 1
jr $ra

ELSE: addi $s0, $a0, 0
addi $a0, $a0, -1
jal fibo;

addi $s1, $v0, 0
addi $a0, $s0, -2
jal fibo

add $s1, $s1, $v0
j EXIT

EXIT: lw $s0, 0($sp)
lw $s1, 4($sp)
lw $ra, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 12

jr $ra
```

Comment: Step through the `fibo` routine in the simulator to see where things start going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

A few issues here.

First, your `main` function was missing its terminating `jr $ra`, meaning that `main` fell through into `fibo` after being executed.

Second, in your `if` statement, where you return `1`, you call `jr $ra` directly, which means the stack goes unrestored. I swapped this out with a call to `j EXIT`.

Finally, at the end of your else you add `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)` into `$s1`. This register should be `$v0` as you are intending to return this result.

The fixed up code is as follows:

```
main: 
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    addi $a0, $zero, 5
    jal fibo

    move $a0 $v0
    li $v0 1
    syscall

    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra

fibo: 
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $s0, 0($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $ra, 8($sp)


    slti $t0, $a0, 2
    beq $t0, $zero, ELSE

    addi $v0, $zero, 1
    j EXIT

    ELSE: 
        addi $s0, $a0, 0
        addi $a0, $a0, -1
        jal fibo

        addi $s1, $v0, 0
        addi $a0, $s0, -2
        jal fibo

        add $v0, $s1, $v0

    EXIT: 
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $ra, 8($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12

    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for the same,but it is written in RISC-V

```
.text

#x5 me n hai
#x7 me output
li x5 7
li x6 2
jal x1 FIB
j EXIT

FIB:
    bge x5 x6 REC 
    addi x7 x5 0
    jalr x0 0(x1)
    #Handled Base Case

REC:
    # Handling Rec. Case

    addi sp sp -12
    sw x1 0(sp)
    sw x5 4(sp)

    addi x5 x5 -1
    jal x1 FIB


    sw x7 8(sp)
    lw x5 4(sp)
    addi x5 x5 -2
    jal x1 FIB 

    lw x13 8(sp)
    add x7 x13 x7


    lw x1 0(sp)
    addi sp sp 12
    jalr x0 0(x1)

EXIT:
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Konrad (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23185991/3729904), I noticed that there is an error in your algorithm. If n<2 the fib algorithm should return n instead of 1.

This can be fixed changing the line:

```
addi $v0, $zero, 1
```

into:

```
add $v0, $zero, $a0
```